# Need an efficient way to plot planes from large sets of 3D coordinates

Tags: python, performance, parallel-processing, cuda, scientific-computing

I have some detector data collected on a 2D camera, I then convert it to a lab frame so I end up with an (`x^2+y^2`) and `z` coordinate for each pixel in the image. But then the object rotates about it's normal and there is an img for each rotation.  I apply a rotation matrix to (`x^2+y^2`) to get `x` and `y` matrices for each `img`, so I end up with something like this for each image/angle. So every pixel has a 3D position and intensity.

```
z                  x            y          img
444444444     123456789     123456789    123456789                  
333333333     123456789     123456789    423466789
222222222     123456789     123456789    223256789
111111111     123456789     123456789    523456689
```

What I want to do then is extract a plane, i.e. plot a map of x, y for a given z range.

The problem is slightly more complicated by the following:

The labframe is actually curved so I can't rely on each row of x and y being the same.
The image size is around 2048x2048x32bits (Tiff) - there can be 1000 images.

My current solution is using CUDA/Numba, I have a function the calculates the `z`,`x`,`y`,`img` for a given angle, so I do that for all the angles. Each time I then slice a number of rows, and extent a list with the raveled the `x`,`y`,`img` values. And then use `scipy.interpolate.griddata` to give a 2d map. `griddata` is pretty slow also, anything on the GPU would probably be better.

The whole process is quite slow, so I'm looking for better solutions or maybe a library already does this? The CUDA code looks something like this,its not so slow it's self:

```
#constants are q0, angi, rot_direction, SDD, k0, Binv
@cuda.jit
    def detector_to_hkl_kernel(h_glob,k_glob,l_glob,omega_rad):
        #get the current thread position
        j,i = cuda.grid(2)

        if j < h_glob.shape[0] and i < h_glob.shape[1]:
            delta_z= (q0[1]-j)*pixel_y  #real-space dinstance from centre pixel y
            delta_x = (i-q0[0])*pixel_x  #real-space dinstance from centre pixel x
            delR = math.sqrt(delta_x**2 + delta_z**2)            
            dist = math.sqrt(delta_x**2+SDD**2 + delta_z**2) #distance to pixel      

            #lab coorindates of pixel in azimuthal angles
            del_pix  = math.atan(delta_x/ SDD)
            gam_pix = math.atan(delta_z/math.sqrt(delta_x**2 + SDD**2))-angi*math.cos(del_pix)
                            
            #lab coordinates in momenturm transfer                                  
            qx = k0*(math.cos(gam_pix)*math.cos(del_pix)-math.cos(angi))
            qy = k0*(math.cos(gam_pix)*math.sin(del_pix)) 
            qz = k0*(math.sin(gam_pix)+math.sin(angi))

            so = math.sin(rotDirection*omega_rad)
            co = math.cos(rotDirection*omega_rad)
            # we deal with the angle of incidence in the momentum transfer calc
            # so that part of the rotation matrix can be fixed
            ci = 1 #math.cos(angi) 
            si = 0 #math.sin(angi)

            #rotation matrix
            hphi_1 = so*(ci*qy+si*qz)+co*qx
            hphi_2 = co*(ci*qy+si*qz)-so*qx
            hphi_3 = ci*qz-si*qy
                
            #H= Binv dot Hphi 
            # compute the dot product manually 
            h_glob[j,i] = Binv[0][0]*hphi_1+Binv[0][1]*hphi_2+Binv[0][2]*hphi_3
            k_glob[j,i] = Binv[1][0]*hphi_1+Binv[1][1]*hphi_2+Binv[1][2]*hphi_3
            l_glob[j,i] = Binv[2][0]*hphi_1+Binv[2][1]*hphi_2+Binv[2][2]*hphi_3              
            
        
    h_global_mem  = cuda.to_device(np.zeros((pixel_count_y,pixel_count_x)))
    k_global_mem  = cuda.to_device(np.zeros((pixel_count_y,pixel_count_x)))
    l_global_mem  = cuda.to_device(np.zeros((pixel_count_y,pixel_count_x)))                  

    # Configure the blocks
    threadsperblock = (16, 16)
    blockspergrid_x = int(math.ceil(pixel_count_y / threadsperblock[0]))
    blockspergrid_y = int(math.ceil(pixel_count_x / threadsperblock[1]))
    blockspergrid = (blockspergrid_x, blockspergrid_y)

    detector_to_hkl_kernel[blockspergrid, threadsperblock](h_global_mem,k_global_mem,l_global_mem, omega_rad)        
    return [h_global_mem.copy_to_host(),k_global_mem.copy_to_host(),l_global_mem.copy_to_host()]
```

Comment: The code does not seems too bad to me (except the trigonometric function calls that may be unavoidable). What GPU do you use?

Comment: I don't see where `delR` or `dist` are used in the kernel. We would hope the kernel optimizes them away, but what is the point of tempting fate with redundant code?

Comment: ahh yeah missed that when I was simplifying for posting, there's a another array of intensity corrections that is computed for each pixel which they are used for. The yeah the main issue is really doing this for lots of images and then taking a plane out of the end result.

Comment: Using a GTX 1660 super, but only because the my 3080 blew up last week (I don't think it is related haha).My quadro's are all 4 or 5 years old now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, note that you use double-precision here and that mainstream middle-end consumer GPUs are *very slow* to compute double-precision floating-point numbers. Indeed, a GTX 1660 Super GPU has a computing power of 5027 GFlops for simple-precision and only 157 GFlops for double-precision (32 times slower). One simple solution is to **use simple-precision floating-point numbers** in your code by specifying `dtype=np.float32` or converting arrays using `array.astype(np.float32)`. An alternative expensive solution could be to use professional GPUs dedicated for that if you cannot use simple precision or mixed-precision.

Moreover, several **expressions can be pre-computed ahead of time** and stored in constants. This includes for example `math.cos(angi)`, `math.sin(angi)` and `1.0/SDD`. Some other expressions can be stored in **temporary variables** as the compiler may not be able to efficiently factorize the code (mainly because of [trigonometric functions](https://godbolt.org/z/sd7YW3Ghj)).

Additionally, trigonometric functions are often very expensive, especially when you want the computation to be IEEE-754 compliant (which is likely the case for `math.xxx` calls). You can use **approximations** instead. CUDA provides the `__cosf`, `__sinf` and `__tanf` intrinsics for that which should be much faster (but be careful of the result if you use them). I am not sure you can call them directly but you can add the parameter **`fastmath=True`** to the JIT decorator which can do that for you.

I think using a 2D thread block of 32x8 may be a bit faster because threads are packed in **warps** containing 32 threads and the GPU. But the best solution is to check the performance with many different block sizes.

If all of this is not enough, you could try to use the **shared memory** to reduce the amount of instruction done per bloc as some expression are recomputed multiple times per bloc.

Comment: I have notice that again happened to you that OP just deletes the question after having the answer to it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67359104/using-openmp-for-simd-in-matrix-vector-multiplication . I think in such cases you can flag the question. Nonetheless, I have voted to undeleted

Comment: @dreamcrash Thank you! I hadn't notice that. I flagged the question since this is a bit suspicious, indeed. Soon, I will be able to see deleted posts :) .

Comment: not sure what you mean about deleting the questions ..

Comment: Also thanks for the tip Jerome, I'll implement them for sure. I've been a bit busy with other work so haven't had a chance to come back to this yet. But the main bottle neck is still extracting a plane/slices out of such 3D data. I guess I need to write some code to do the histogramming/interpolation also on the GPU also - if only I could parallelise myself.

Comment: In the end I solved this by binning to a grid and using atomic add